# Insufficient memory to continue the execution of the program. Creating Xlxs from CSV

Tags: excel, powershell

I have a script that cycles through a folder and condenses multiple CSVs to one xlsx file with the names of the CSV as worksheets. However, when the script runs as part of a larger script it failes when it refreshes the query.

```
$Query.Refresh()
```

On its own the script runs fine, but when added to the larger one it fails. Can anyone advise why this is the case?

Below is the error I get:

```
Insufficient memory to continue the execution of the program.
At C:\Temp\Scripts\Shares_Complete.psm1:254 char:13
+             $Query.Refresh()
+             ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : OperationStopped: (:) [], OutOfMemoryException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.OutOfMemoryException
```

I have tried single csv with the same code and still the same result.

```
$script:SP = "C:\Temp\Servers\"

$script:TP = "C:\Temp\Servers\Pc.txt"
$script:FSCSV = "C:\Temp\Server_Shares\Server Lists\"
$script:Message1 = "Unknown Hosts"
$script:Message2 = "Unable to connect"
$script:Message3 = "Unknown Errors Occurred"
$script:Txt = ".txt"
$script:OT = ".csv"
$script:FSERROR1 = $FSCSV+$Message1+$OT
$script:FSERROR2 = $FSCSV+$Message2+$OT
$script:FSERROR3 = $FSCSV+$Message2+$OT

$script:ERL3 = $E4 + "Shares_Errors_$Date.txt"
$script:ECL1 = $E4 + "Shares_Exceptions1_$Date.txt"
$script:ERL1 = $E4 + "Shares_Errors1_$Date.txt"
$script:ECL3 = $E4 + "Shares_Exceptions_$Date.txt"

function Excel-Write {
    if ($V -eq "1") {
        return
    }

    [System.GC]::Collect()
    $RD = $FSCSV + "*.csv" 
    $CsvDir = $RD 
    $Ma4 = $FSCSV + "All Server Shares for Domain $CH4"
    $csvs = dir -path $CsvDir # Collects all the .csv's from the driectory 
    $FSh = $csvs | Select-Object -First 1
    $FSh = ($FSh -Split "\\")[4]
    $FSh = $FSh -replace ".{5}$"
    $FSh
    $outputxls = "$Ma4.xlsx"
    $script:Excel = New-Object -ComObject Excel.Application
    $Excel.DisplayAlerts = $false
    $workbook = $excel.Workbooks.Add()
    # Loops through each CVS, pulling all the data from each one
    foreach ($iCsv in $csvs) {
        $script:iCsv
        $WN = ($iCsv -Split "\\")[-1]
        $WN = $WN -replace ".{4}$"
        if ($WN.Length -gt 30) {
            $WN = $WN.Substring(0, [Math]::Min($WN.Length, 20))
        }
        $Excel = New-Object -ComObject Excel.Application
        $Excel.DisplayAlerts = $false
        $Worksheet = $workbook.Worksheets.Add()
        $Worksheet.Name = $WN

        $TxtConnector = ("TEXT;" + $iCsv)
        $Connector = $worksheet.Querytables.Add($txtconnector,$worksheet.Range("A1"))
        $query = $Worksheet.QueryTables.Item($Connector.Name)

        $query.TextfileOtherDelimiter = $Excel.Application.International(5)

        $Query.TextfileParseType = 1
        $Query.TextFileColumnDataTypes = ,2 * $worksheet.Cells.Column.Count
        $query.AdjustColumnWidth = 1

        $Query.Refresh()
        $Query.Delete()
        $Worksheet.Cells.EntireColumn.AutoFit()
        $Worksheet.Rows.Item(1).Font.Bold = $true
        $Worksheet.Rows.Item(1).HorizontalAlignment = -4108
        $Worksheet.Rows.Item(1).Font.Underline = $true
        $Workbook.Save()
    }
    $Empty = $workbook.Worksheets.Item("Sheet1")
    $Empty.Delete()
    $Workbook.SaveAs($outputxls,51)
    $Workbook.Close()
    $Excel.Quit()
    $ObjForm.Close()
    Delete
}
```

Should continue script and create the xlsx.

Comment: You clearly run out of memory. How much data do you have?

Comment: You're creating a new Excel instance with every iteration of the loop. Don't do that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looking at your script, it doesn't surprise me you eventually run out of memory, because you are continouisly creating Com objects and never release them from memory.

Whenever you have created Com objects and finished with them, use these lines to free up the memory:

```
$Excel.Quit()
[System.Runtime.Interopservices.Marshal]::ReleaseComObject($workbook) | Out-Null
[System.Runtime.Interopservices.Marshal]::ReleaseComObject($Excel) | Out-Null
[System.GC]::Collect()
[System.GC]::WaitForPendingFinalizers()
```

Also, take a good look at the code.
You are creating a `$Script:Excel = New-Object -ComObject excel.application` object before the `foreach` loop but you don't use that. Instead, you are creating new Excel and workbook objects inside the loop over and over again where there is absolutely no reason for it since you can re-use the one you created before the loop.

As an aside: The following characters are not allowed in excel worksheet names

```
\/?*[]:
```

Length limitation is 31 characters.

---

**EDIT**

---

I had a look at your project and especially the `Shares_Complete.psm1` file.
Although I'm not willing of course to rewrite your entire project, I do have some remarks that may help you:

1. `[System.Net.Dns]::GetHostByName()` is obsolete. Use [GetHostEntry()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.dns.gethostentry?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Net_Dns_GetHostEntry_System_String_)
2. when done with a Windows form, use `$ObjForm.Dispose()` to clear it from memory
3. you do a lot of `[System.GC]::Collect(); [System.GC]::WaitForPendingFinalizers()` for no reason
4. Why not use `[System.Windows.MessageBox]::Show()` instead of using a Com object `$a = new-object -comobject wscript.shell`. Again you leave that object lingering in memory..
5. use `Join-Path` cmdlet instead of `$RD = $FSCSV + "*.csv"` or `$Cop = $FSCSV + "*.csv"` constructs
6. remove invalid characters from Excel worksheet names (`replace '[\\/?*:[\]]', ''`)
7. use [Verb-Noun](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/learn/learning-powershell-names?view=powershell-6) names for your functions so it becomes clear what they do. Now you have functions like `Location`, `Delete` and `File` that don't mean anything
8. you are calling functions before they are defined like in line 65 where you call function `Shares`. At that point it does not exist yet because the function itself is written in line 69
9. add `[System.Runtime.Interopservices.Marshal]::ReleaseComObject($worksheet) | Out-Null` in function `Excel-Write`
10. there is no need to use the variable `$Excel` in script scope (`$Script:Excel = New-Object -ComObject excel.application`) where it is used only locally to the function.
11. you may need to look at [Excel specifications and limits](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/excel-specifications-and-limits-1672b34d-7043-467e-8e27-269d656771c3)
12. fix your indentation of code so it is clear when a loop or if starts and ends
13. I would recommend using variable names with more meaning. For an outsider or even yourself after a couple of months two-letter variable names become confusing

Comment: These are great answers @Theo I have removed the duplicates and still get the same error. any ideas how I can free up the memory for the rest of the script?

Comment: @bob500000 I can't see what you have changed in the code (you didn't edit your question) and there is no telling what 'the rest of your script' does, so no... Just keep in mind that whenever you have used a Com object, you need to clear it from memory using the lines in my answer. (also, you really don't need to make every variable `$Script:...` I think)

Comment: I Can post the entire script but its quite large, in essense what it does is collects all the CSVs in a folder and converts them to one xlsx using the names of the csvs as worksheet names.

Comment: @bob500000 Yes, that much was clear to me. However, using the code I gave should get your script running without gobbling up memory. You might also have a look at [Workbook.Close](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.workbook.close), [Join-Path](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/join-path?view=powershell-6) examples. P.s. What does `Delete` do in the final line and what form are you closing, but not DISPOSING?

Comment: The delete is a function to remove some unwanted Items, the form is just a progressbar. It is a complex script that does the following;

User has a list of servers
Script gets a list shares on each server
Script then creates a csv for each server with shares
Then it cycles through each cvs in folder creating an xlsx containing all the information.

Comment: @bob500000 Yes, but simply closing a form also keeps it in memory. When done with it do `$Form.Dispose()`. There may be lots more of this in your script you need to hunt down.

Comment: @bob500000 I have added remarks/observations/recommendations about your script. Hope that helps. (I didn't save it somewhere, just peeked)

Comment: Thanks for your help. I have implemented the changes and seems to be running much better now.